# How to calculate electronegativity for an atom?

Tags: atoms

So there is Pauling electronegativity scale, but thous are constants based on experiments, right? Another way is Allred-Rochow method, but it has rumors being a bit imprecise comparing to real measurements. Are there any other good methods where I can calculate electronegativity given electron configuration?